# Changing arguments in seg.control() while maintaining psi = NA

Tags: r, piecewise

I have a [dataset](https://gist.github.com/Shanicus/e2237cdef25f48ee590d80fee8b2b0f7) that I'm trying to fit a piecewise linear regression model using [segmented()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html). I wanted to leave the `psi = NA` because I have several "transects" of data that require a piecewise model to be fitted. The trouble is that I keep getting one of two errors:

```
Error in segmented.lm(transect.lm, seg.Z = ~distance, psi = NA, control = seg.control(n.boot = 30,  : 
  only 1 datum in an interval: breakpoint(s) at the boundary or too close each other
```

```
Error: at least one coef is NA: breakpoint(s) at the boundary? (possibly with many x-values replicated)
```

I want to leave `psi` as `NA`. Can anything within `seg.control` be changed to prevent the error?

Here is I put in for the segmented model:

```
transect.lm <- lm(elevation~length, data = data2)
transect.pw <- segmented(transect.lm, 
                          seg.Z = ~length, 
                          psi = NA, 
                          control = seg.control(
                            n.boot = 30, 
                            h = 0.001, 
                            stop.if.error = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a post in R-Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/error-handling-in-r/) that talked about how to manage errors in for loops. The part of the for loop that was giving me trouble can be within a `try()` command. Within the article, R would just skip over it and continue on its analysis, but I found with my for loop, it would cycle back and try again, so it ended up looking like this:

```
transect.lm <- lm(elevation~length, data = data2)
try(transect.pw <- segmented(transect.lm, 
                          seg.Z = ~length, 
                          psi = NA, 
                          control = seg.control(
                            n.boot = 30, 
                            h = 0.001)))
```

Errors would still be printed to let me know something wrong happened, but it would loop back and try again until a model was fitted, and then move to the next transect.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hard-code the `psi` argument, you could do something like this:

If you think the breakpoint will be near the beginning:

```
segmented(transect.lm, seg.Z = ~length, psi = sort(data2$length)[2])
```

If you think the breakpoint will be near the middle:

```
segmented(transect.lm, seg.Z = ~length, psi = median(data2$length))
```

If you think the breakpoint will be near the end:

```
segmented(transect.lm, seg.Z = ~length, psi = sort(data2$length, decreasing = TRUE)[2])
```

Regardless, I've found that `segmented()` will converge pretty well on whatever part of the dataset is best even if I set `psi` for a value pretty far from the convergence point.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean by "transects" now. I'm assuming you're expecting a varying number of breakpoints for each dataset?

Comment: Yup, exactly! I used a for loop to fit a piecewise linear model through each transect, hence why `psi = NA`, so that I get a certain number of break points specific to that transect. Would it help if you saw my for loop?

Answer (score 0):

`try(., silent = T)` and `seg.control(stop.if.error = F)` are no longer useful for suppressing this kind of error.

You may want to try limit the `it.max` or `n.boot` in the `seg.control()` and turn on the `display = T` so you can have a clue on what is going on.